# How to compile c++ apps from Windows for Amazon's EC2 CentOS 5?

Tags: c++, qt, amazon-ec2, mingw, centos

I want to compile c++ apps (x32 and x64) from scripts in Windows for executing in Amazon EC2 Linux AMI. Linux AMI is based on CentOS 5. So i need toolchain for CentOS in Windows. I never compile apps for Linux from Windows so i am needed little help.
What i need to do? What is best for me: MinGW or Cygwin? 
Do i need to copy include folders of devel packages for standard libs (libstdc++, glibc or other)? I already copied include folders of compiled Qt 4.7.x (i compiled it inside running EC2 instance). 
What options i need to specify inside .pro files for compile qt apps in Windows for Linux? I am using only qt-core and  qt-network. All apps are command line apps

Comment: Installing CentOS 5 in a virtual machine may be *way* easier than cross-compiling from Windows. That way, you can also test the program locally.

Answer (score 1):

I **strongly recommend installing Linux** (a distribution similar to what Amazon gives you) inside a virtual machine on your Windows machine. It is probably much simpler and quicker than trying to build a cross-compiler, cross-compile a GNU libc, cross-compile a Qt, etc...

MinGW (or Cygwin) is not a cross-compiler on Windows targeting Linux, it is a native compiler (with a sort of Posix emulator library). It is not able to produce Linux ELF executables on Windows.

Comment: For testing purpose it is useful. But i need it for long time using. Also i already compiled qt library itself. I need way to tell linker that i have different set of libraries.

Comment: You didn't cross-compile Qt for Linux under Windows, otherwise you won't have asked the question !!!

Comment: I didn't say that i cross-compile. As i said in question i run linux ami at ec2, download qt source within amazon ec2 instance, compile qt with --embedded option. That all.